# How to achieve single sign on for Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

Does MailChimp OAuth2 supports the single sign on feature?
Or do we need to have another service which supports single sign on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done research and finally came a conclusion that we can achieve single sign on in mailchimp is using OAuth2.

Thanks

Comment: How? Can you post your code? Are you using API v 3.0 ?